# ODBC SQL Server Driver - Incorrect syntax near '44444' error - on recordset.UpdateBatch method

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, amazon-web-services, adodb, recordset

VB.Net windows forms program runs properly in "production" environment (i.e. the .EXE runs on a Windows 2008R2 Server, connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database on another server).

The platform was cloned in conjunction to a move to the "test" environment (i.e hosting on AWS; the database server was upgraded to SQL Server 2016 by the sysadmin who is managing the transition to AWS).

Question: Does this error in the test on AWS point to a SQL 2016 configuration problem of some type?

Code snippet follows:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection()
cn.ConnectionString = BuildConnectStringODBC()
cn.Open()
rs = New Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset
rs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic
rs.Open("ImportTempTable", cn)
rs.AddNew()
rs.Fields("StateCD").Value = CRMortgage.StateCD
rs.Fields("CountyCD").Value = CRMortgage.CountyCD                
' etc.
rs.UpdateBatch()
```

Single-step debugging shows that all of the above methods on the rs object work correctly until **rs.UpdateBatch** which fails with the "incorrect syntax" error.

This program has executed without problems many times in "production" and the sysadmin guy and I suspect something with SQL server configuration or options but we are unsure where to even start.

**EDIT UPDATE:**

Here is the scripted schema for the ImportTempTable from SQL Mgmt Studio:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ImportTempTable](
    [StateCD] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [CountyCD] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [SaleMnYear] [datetime] NULL,
    [LenderName] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [MDSID] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [Amt_PUR] [int] NULL,
    [Nbr_MTG] [int] NULL,
    [Amt_MTG] [int] NULL,
    [Nbr_JUMBO] [int] NULL,
    [Amt_JUMBO] [int] NULL,
    [Nbr_GOVT] [int] NULL,
    [Amt_GOVT] [int] NULL,
    [Nbr_Fixed] [int] NULL,
    [Nbr_ARMS] [int] NULL,
    [Nbr_NewConst] [int] NULL,
    [Amt_Fixed] [int] NULL,
    [Amt_ARMS] [int] NULL,
    [Amt_NewConst] [int] NULL,
    [LTV] [real] NULL,
    [Nbr_Below80] [int] NULL,
    [Nbr_80_85] [int] NULL,
    [Nbr_85_90] [int] NULL,
    [Nbr_Above90] [int] NULL,
    [LoanType] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [SaleType] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [RateType] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [CondoCode] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [ZipSuffix] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [StateAbbr] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [DateImported] [datetime] NULL,
    [RecordType] [varchar](1) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Investigating, I did indeed find two triggers associated with the above table:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ImportTempTable_ITrig] ON [dbo].[ImportTempTable] FOR INSERT AS
/*
 * PREVENT NULL VALUES IN 'SaleMnYear'
 */
IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM inserted WHERE SaleMnYear IS NULL) > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR 44444 'Field ''SaleMnYear'' cannot contain a null value.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
ELSE 
/*
 * PREVENT NULL VALUES IN 'LenderName'
 */
IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM inserted WHERE LenderName IS NULL) > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR 44444 'Field ''LenderName'' cannot contain a null value.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

and

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ImportTempTable_UTrig] ON [dbo].[ImportTempTable] FOR UPDATE AS
/*
 * PREVENT NULL VALUES IN 'SaleMnYear'
 */
IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM inserted WHERE SaleMnYear IS NULL) > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR 44444 'Field ''SaleMnYear'' cannot contain a null value.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
ELSE 
/*
 * PREVENT NULL VALUES IN 'LenderName'
 */
IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM inserted WHERE LenderName IS NULL) > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR 44444 'Field ''LenderName'' cannot contain a null value.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

I did not know these triggers were in place. I will rethink the reason for their existence. Perhaps for the 1st time in years we got "bad data" and thus raised this silly error. I thought the NULL attribute on the column definitions above would allow NULLs; this trigger approach seems ill-advised.

Is there something at the instance level in SQL that can enable or disable triggers? I think not...

A bit more research should resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you show the DB query & table structure? I think '44444' is an error code which tells that 'field X cannot contain null value'. Check if your query trying to insert null value into a non-nullable column when executing batch update, or a trigger attached to the table incorrectly (also check triggers section).

Comment: Thank  you, Tetsuya, I will show the table structure. Yet the database was migrated intact to a new instance of SQL 2016. Do you know of any instance level option or configuration choice that might have some affect on this previously working program?

Comment: I think somewhere in your query or database trigger handling may contain this statement: `RAISERROR 44444 '%message_text%'`. You need to change it into a SQL function: `RAISERROR(44444, '%message_text%')`.

Comment: Many thanks. I found the crazy trigger. Please see EDIT UPDATE above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Incorrect syntax near '44444'` error indicates that the SQL triggers use undocumented version of `RAISERROR` syntax which supported up to SQL Server 2008 R2. The undocumented `RAISERROR` syntax already unsupported from SQL Server 2012 onwards, therefore you need to use supported [`RAISERROR` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) or use [`THROW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql) as replacement:

```sql
-- RAISERROR example
RAISERROR(44444, -1, -1, 'Field ''SaleMnYear'' cannot contain a null value.');

-- THROW example
THROW 44444, 'Field ''SaleMnYear'' cannot contain a null value.', 1;
```

Additionally you can try drop both `ImportTempTable_ITrig` & `ImportTempTable_UTrig` triggers from `ImportTempTable` then set column `SaleMnYear` & `LenderName` to non-nullable data type, no triggers necessary as of newer SQL Server versions to check against null values.

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [dbo].[ImportTempTable_ITrig]
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [dbo].[ImportTempTable_UTrig]

-- if the table already contains null value, update them first
UPDATE [dbo].[ImportTempTable] SET SaleMnYear = {value}, LenderName = {value} 
WHERE SaleMnYear IS NULL {AND/OR} LenderName IS NULL

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ImportTempTable] ALTER COLUMN SaleMnYear {data_type} NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ImportTempTable] ALTER COLUMN LenderName {data_type} NOT NULL
```

As of `RecordSet.UpdateBatch` which halts with error above, it supposed that running ADO update process tried to add null value(s) into either `SaleMnYear` or `LenderName` column which set to disallow null value by if-condition triggers in question (ensure that records in source data column not containing nulls).

NB: I recommend to use managed `SqlClient.SqlConnection` over ODBC's `ADODB.Connection` to handle SQL Server connection instances.

Reference:

[Differences between RAISERROR and THROW in SQL Server](http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/)

Similar issues:

[Migrating from SQL Server 2008r2 to SQL Sever 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908329/migrating-from-sql-server-2008r2-to-sql-sever-2012)

[RAISERROR issue since migration to SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669227/raiserror-issue-since-migration-to-sql-server-2012)

Comment: Thank you for a first-class answer!